# PHP/Ajax - can't get value from texture in form? No errors?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have used this method with inputs but am having a problem with my textarea- I need to get the value from the texture on enter and echo it back out in a PHP file, however I can't get the values entered. In fact I can't get ANY output from the PHP form at all even though I am linking to the right folder. I don't know where the problem is.

Here is my form:

[image]

Javascript to send value:

[image]

PHP form where not even "hi" is echoed:

[image]

I would think the Ajax request had not succeeded however the success output "BLURB WORKS" is printed. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Running the PHP by itself I am getting this-

[image]

Comment: Change in php code at line no 17:
$blurbtxt=$_POST['newBlurb'];

Answer (score 0):

`Line 23` in JavaScript: Change `newBlurb` into `blurbEdit`

Comment: did not work. Same error

Comment: It cannot find the index blurbEdit

Comment: Line 22 JavaScript: change `type: "POST"` into `method: "POST"`